# Почему экран мерцает и обновляется, когда я пытаюсь указать количество блоков при помощикласса random?

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа, android-canvas

Вот мне нужно сделать чтобы отрисовывалось разное количество блоков,добавил random,но Блоки(именно блоки) стали вечно обновляться и менять свое количество,как изменить код,что сделать,чтобы при запуске сгенерировалось рандомное кол-во и они не так и остались пока я не закрою игру?надеюсь вы поняли,код:

```
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  Random random = new Random();
  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
  int xd = -100;//x
  int xy = 474;//y
  int min = 5;//минимальное количество блоков 
  int max = 10;//максимальное количество блоков 
  int diff = max - min;//
  int st;//переменная для цикла 
  int stocks = random.nextInt(diff + min);//само рандомное число 
  for(st=0;st<stock;st++){//сколько блоков нужно создать 
  xd = xd + 100;//где рисовать 
  canvas.drawBitmap(dirtes,xd,xy, null);//рисуем
  }
}
```

Comment: вам нужно вынести генерацию из onDraw(), так как onDraw вызывается не один раз

Comment: Большое спасибо,заработало

Comment: написал ответ, пометьте пожалуйста правильным, чтобы вопрос не выскакивал в неотвеченных, спасибо)

Comment: Пометил,вам спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onDraw()` вызывается 60 раз в секунду, а не один раз. Следовательно, в данном случае мы не можем генерировать информацию о рисовании в `onDraw()`, если она не должна меняться 60 раз в секунду.

В данном случае надо вынести всё, что не касается рисования, из `onDraw()`.